# checking if input from scanner is int with while loop java

Tags: java, while-loop

I basically want the following while loop to check if the input is an integer. It cannot contain decimals because it is pointing to an array. If the value entered is a decimal it should prompt the user again. Problem is I get two prompts before the while loop starts with this code. Any ideas?

```
      System.out.print("Enter month (valid values are from 1 to 12): ");
    Scanner monthScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int monthInput = monthScan.nextInt();
    // If the month input is below 1 or greater than 12, prompt for another value
    while(monthInput<1 || monthInput>12 || !monthScan.hasNextInt())
    {
        System.out.print("Invalid value! Enter month (valid values are from 1 to 12): ");
        monthInput = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    }
```

thanks

EDIT: The current output gives the following:

```
Enter month (valid values are from 1 to 12): 2
2
```

Notice how I had to enter 2 twice even though it is a valid value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small modification to your program solves the problem

```
 System.out.print("Enter month (valid values are from 1 to 12): ");
        Scanner monthScan = new Scanner(System.in);
       int monthInput = monthScan.nextInt();
        // If the month input is below 1 or greater than 12, prompt for another value
        while((monthInput<1 || monthInput>12) )
        {
            System.out.print("Invalid value! Enter month (valid values are from 1 to 12): ");

            monthInput = monthScan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("I am here");
```

Output:

```
Enter month (valid values are from 1 to 12): -5
Invalid value! Enter month (valid values are from 1 to 12): -5
Invalid value! Enter month (valid values are from 1 to 12): -2
Invalid value! Enter month (valid values are from 1 to 12): 5
I am here
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 4):

Check that the input is integer with `hasNextInt()` before you call `nextInt()`. Otherwise `nextInt()` throws an `InputMismatchException` when  user types a non integer.

```
int monthInput;

System.out.print("Enter month (valid values are from 1 to 12): ");
Scanner monthScan = new Scanner(System.in);

if (monthScan.hasNextInt()) {
    monthInput = monthScan.nextInt();
} else {
    monthScan.next();   // get the inputted non integer from scanner
    monthInput = 0;
}

// If the month input is below 1 or greater than 12, prompt for another value
while (monthInput < 1 || monthInput > 12) {
    System.out.print("Invalid value! Enter month (valid values are from 1 to 12): ");
    if (monthScan.hasNextInt()) {
        monthInput = monthScan.nextInt();
     } else {
       String dummy = monthScan.next();
       monthInput = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can check like this

```
System.out.print("Enter month (valid values are from 1 to 12): ");
Scanner monthScan = new Scanner(System.in);

while(monthScan.hasNext())
{
   if(!monthScan.hasNextInt() && (monthInput<1 ||  monthInput>12))
   {
       System.out.print("Invalid value! Enter month (valid values are from 1 to 12):"); 
       continue;
   }

   // If the month input is below 1 or greater than 12, prompt for another value
  int monthInput = monthScan.nextInt();
  //do your logic here   
  break;//use the break after logic 

}
```

**update**
Use `break` after your logic so that It will exit after valid input.

Comment: Doesn't work. I end up getting an infinite loop of prompts regardless if the input is valid or not.